# Difficulty Booting into Ubuntu - "Reset System" Message

Tags: 22.04

Subject: Difficulty Booting into Ubuntu - "Reset System" Message

Hello Ubuntu Community,

I'm encountering an issue with my dual-boot setup of Ubuntu and Windows 11. When I restart my computer, I consistently see a message that says "Reset System" instead of the expected GRUB menu.

System Details:

Computer model/specifications: [Insert your computer details]
Operating systems: Ubuntu [Version], Windows [Version]
Boot mode: UEFI/Legacy [Specify]
Secure Boot: Enabled/Disabled [Specify]
Steps Taken:

Set GRUB_TIMEOUT to a non-zero value in /etc/default/grub.
Confirmed that the correct drive is set as the first boot option in UEFI/BIOS.
Attempted automatic repairs using Boot Repair.
Observations:

[Any specific error messages encountered]
[Details of any unexpected behavior]
Additional Information:

[Any other relevant details about your setup]
I have followed various troubleshooting steps without success. Any guidance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance for your assistance.